# Exponentially scale the Y axis level with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph created with `mathplotlib`. Here is my code:

```
# Multiline Graph
dataset = ['10:00 AM', '12:00 PM', '2:00 PM', '4:00 PM', '6:00 PM', '8:00 PM', '10:00 PM', '12:00 AM', '2:00 AM', '4:00 AM', '6:00 AM', '8:00 AM']
y_axis = [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]


plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

CO2 = [545, 656, 614, 60, 563, 615, 57, 462, 57, 454, 535, 447]
LPG = [27, 26, 26, 30, 26, 28, 24, 25, 26, 27, 26, 26]
CH4 = [90, 85, 87, 95, 85, 89, 83, 82, 83, 81, 84, 85]
CO = [0.863, 0.725, 0.962, 1.207, 0.805, 0.603, 1.157, 0.783, 0.812, 0.760, 0.637, 0.778]

plt.plot(dataset,CO2,label='CO2',color='#FFC000',linewidth=3,marker='.',markersize=12,linestyle='-')
plt.plot(dataset,LPG,label='LPG',color='#5B9BD5',linewidth=3,marker='s',markersize=8,linestyle='-')
plt.plot(dataset,CH4,label='CH4',color='#404040',linewidth=3,marker='+',markersize=10,linestyle='-')
plt.plot(dataset,CO,label='CO',color='#ED7D31',linewidth=3,marker='*',markersize=12,linestyle='-')

plt.xticks(dataset)
plt.yticks(y_axis)

plt.xlabel('X-Axis Title')
plt.ylabel('Y-Axis Title')

axes = plt.gca()
axes.yaxis.grid()

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02,0.5), loc="center left", borderaxespad=0)
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0,0,0.95,1])

#plt.savefig('your_graph_name.eps',dpi=300)
#files.download("your_graph_name.eps") 

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

It works perfectly, But to fit all the curves nicely, it would be better if the Y-axis level distance distribution becomes exponential. Please suggest how can I do this?

Comment: Use `axes.set_yscale('log')`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Works for me using the exact code you posted - try adding it just before the `plt.show()` line.

Comment: Thanks now it works